# Vim lagging when pressing k at the top of a file

Tags: vim, lag

If I press k for 1 second when I'm on the top of a file, vim seems to be lagging for something like 3-4 seconds (eg not responding to any input).

(Same happens if I press j on the bottom of a file)

I have changed the Operating System keyboard settings, eg :

- Repeat Delay: **256**
- Repat Speed:  **74**

However this is a bit annoying.

Is there any way to solve that ?

[Here is my .vimrc](https://gist.github.com/edi9999/23af85379811f3a5fa97) if it has something to do with that:

Comment: Didn't see anything odd in your .vimrc, but why are you setting five different colorschemes one after the other?!

Comment: Yeah that's kind of weird, these are my 5 favorite color schemes, I should comment the 4 that I don't use.

Comment: It was because of the `visualbell` option.

Comment: Please add that an an answer to mark this question closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because of the `visualbell` option